# Find distinct numbers in an array

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, distinct-values

Using this following code:

```
public static int countDistinct(int a[])
    {
        int U_size = 1;
        int j; int i;
        for ( i = 2; i < a.length; i++ ) 
        {
            boolean U = true;
            for ( j = 1; j < U_size; j++ ) 
            {
                if ( a[j] == a[i] )
                {
                    U = false;
                    j=U_size;
                }
            }
            if (U=true)
            {
                U_size = U_size+1; 
                a[U_size]=a[i];
            }

        }
        return U_size;
    }
```

I wrote this algorithm in order to find the amount of distinct numbers in the array and rearrange them at the beginning of the array

But, for example for the inputed array:

```
int arr[] = { 3,1,2,9,5 };
```

I should get the output `5` but all I get is `4` and the elements in the array are not shifted to the relevant place

> Please, if anyone can help me identify the problem in my algorithm?

Comment: Your loops are starting to count from 1 and 2. Arrays are zero-indexed. Perhaps that's related?

Comment: So you never look at the first element?  And if you determine the last element is distinct, you write past the end of the array?  `a[1]` doesn't get you the first element, it gets you the second one.

Comment: Also for the input of `array = {1,1,1,1,5}` the outpput will be `4`, I think the problem is that it skips the if conditon inside the inner loop

Comment: I suspect that the indexing might be the issue. Currently, your code never looks at `a[0]`, so if you're trying to count the number of distinct items in the array, you might get the wrong answer depending on whether `a[0]` is a duplicate of another item.

Comment: Thank you, but, yet it does not explain why every output is `n-1` when the size of the array is `n`

Comment: What is `U` used for? Can you explain to yourself what the algorithm does? most of the times, if you can't, debugging is just a waste of time

Comment: Instead of `j=U_size;` to break your loop, you could just use `break;`.  Also, `if (U=true)` is an assignment not a comparison... should be `if (U==true)`

Comment: @Dmitri  About to say that.   However, I encourage folks to test as a boolean -- `if(U) {...`

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri , but the output is still incorrect. For inputed `array = {1,1,1,1,1}`, the output is: `2`

Comment: @WJS The array would have to be empty to have no distinct values..

Comment: @WJS I think in this case `{1,1,2,2,3,3}` would count as 3 distinct values.  Basically each value gets counted only once.

Comment: @WJS distinct values => only the different values in the array. You can look at it as a smaller array => `int vDistinct[] = {1,2,3}`, `vDistinct_size=3`. distinct = adjective (DIFFERENT)

Comment: Start your outer loop at 1, your inner one at 0, and swap the lines in the last `if`

Comment: @Dmitri King. I would be happy for an explanation if you may

Comment: You were indexing your arrays as if the first value is at `a[1]` for the most part, except when checking for the end (less than the size is correct, as it makes the last index size - 1).  Changing the starting indices for the loops fixes that so you don't ignore the first element.  Also, swapping the lines in the `if` means you set the next element after your old subarray, instead of the one two elements after (`U_size` is the size, and the index of the first element *past* the end -- so when you extend the subarray you should increment it *after* using it as the new last index).

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @OmriBraha Then I interpreted it incorrectly.  I was going by other questions I have seen.  You might want to edit  your question to show some duplicates in the original array and the final result as others may gain some insight into this question.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I see what you are doing I thought I would pass on some potentially useful information.  I eliminated the `booleans` and this seems to work.  If you place a label on the outer loop you can continue on that loop if you encounter a seen value.  Otherwise, it falls thru and you update the first portion of the array and `U_size`.

```
public static int countDistinct(int a[]) {
    int U_size = 1;
    outer: for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < U_size; j++) {
            if (a[i] == a[j]) {
                // already seen
                continue outer;
            }
        }
        a[U_size++] = a[i];
    }
    return U_size;
}
```

And here is a way to test it.

- Create an array of values that are guaranteed to have duplicates.
- then Stream the array and count the distinct values.
- then compare that result to yours.

```
ThreadLocalRandom r = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
int iterations = 100;
int streamSize = 1000;
int maxRandomNumber = 200;
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    int[] testData = r.ints(streamSize,0,maxRandomNumber).toArray();
    long count = Arrays.stream(testData).distinct().count();
    int yourCount = countDistinct(testData);
    if (count != yourCount) {
        System.out.println("Oops!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Looking through your code, there are parts of it that I would improve upon. First of all, the reason why your code does not affect the original array is because is "pass-by-value". This just means that editing parameters passed into a method does **NOT** affect the variable you entered. If you really want to change the order of the list, a better way would be to have a method that returns a new list.

A better way to get the number of unique values would be to use a set. A set can contain at most one of each unique value, so converting a list to a set, then getting the size of that set tells you the number of unique entries. Here is what I would do to get the number of unique values:

```
public static int newCountDistinct(ArrayList<Integer> numbers) {
    return (new HashSet<Integer>(numbers)).size();
}
```

Comment: Arrays are passed via a reference so the values will be affected.  And returning a list doesn't solve the problem.  The idea is to return a count of distinct values.

Comment: Regarding an Hashset solution: I am familiure with this method, but I wanted to examine what is wrong with my code. As far as run-time or any other consideration - I chose the igonore this time only ( My algorithm runs in O(n^2) )